# Open external URL from GWT application

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to open external URL from my website using GWT
I tried both these methods:

1. `HTML html = new HTML("<a href=\"" + p.getUrl() + "\">" + p.getTitle() + "</a>");`
2. `Anchor arch = new Anchor(p.getTitle(),true,p.getUrl(),"_blank" );`

in this case: `p.getUrl()` returns `www.google.com`

In both cases i see in my browser a link, but when i click on it i'm getting this error message:

> HTTP ERROR: 404 NOT_FOUND
>   RequestURI=/www.google.com

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Correction to #1:HTML html = new HTML("<a href=\"" + p.getUrl() + "\">" + p.getTitle() + "</a>");

Comment: Inspect the output HTML code and paste it here please.

Answer (score 2):

Start your URL off correctly - your url must be `http://www.google.com` or `https://www.google.com`, not simply `www.google.com`.

The bare url `www.google.com` works when you type it into the web browser's address bar because it isn't being requested from within another page - when a page asks for a url that doesnt begin with <schema>://, the browser thinks that this is a different page relative to the current one, not a totally new url.